# Low hot water pressure

Tags: water, gas, heater

I have a gas water heater. Put in in 09. Low after pressure in all faucets. Have drained water heater, changed piping to pex and new pressure valve. Still same low pressure. Could it be heater itself?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. The water heater will have a drain; how is the pressure there?

Comment: Is this a tank water heater (WH)? What piping did you change to PEX? Did you replace the cut-off valve in the cold feed to the WH?

Answer (score 1):

So you have low flow rate out *all* the hot water lines. This indicates a restriction in the hot water system which could be in a pipe or in a valve. The latter is more likely in my experience.

The restriction could be in the cold water line that feeds the water heater or it could be in the hot water line before the dividing into the various usually smaller lines that go to different areas.

All systems have a cut-off valve on the cold water feed to the water heater. Sometimes these valves develop a restriction, if they are of the old gate valve type. I am not aware of quarter-turn ball valves developing restrictions.

Some systems in addition have a cut-off valve on the hot side of the water heater. This valve could also develop a restriction. Do you have one of these?

Did you recently operate one of these valves before this low flow condition has occurred?

Comment: I've replaced many gate valves... they're a big problem.